# Netware - display user groups

Tags: novell, login-script

Is there command in netware that will allow me to display all groups that user belongs to in login script?

Comment: what version of netware?

Comment: Novell NetWare 5.00

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used Netware, but I think the variable %GROUP_MEMBERSHIP should give you what you're looking for. So adding something like

```
WRITE "You're a member of the following groups..." 
WRITE "%GROUP_MEMBERSHIP"
```

should give you a listing of the groups that the user is a member of.

Comment: it works partially - my user belongs to two groups, but only one was printed

Comment: How about using nlist via the login script

NLIST USER=%LOGIN_NAME SHOW "Group Membership"